# How to make an input required based on the value of another input?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two HTML form fields in my application, one displays a dropdown for users to select if they are over 18 and the second field is for parent's name.

I want to make the `parent_name` field `required` only if the user is under 18. Here's my current code for the appropriate form parts.

```
<div>
  <label for="over_18">Over 18?</label>
  <select id="over_18" required multiple>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Parent Name</label>
  <input type="parent_name" id="parent_name" required>
</div>
```

I've created the following function so far, but I'm unable to understand how to use it.

```
function updateRequirements() {
  var over_18 = document.getElementById('over_18').value;
  if (over_18 = 'No') {
    doccument.getElementById('parent_name').required = true;
  } else {
    doccument.getElementById('parent_name').required = false;
  }
}
```

**Update:**

How to achieve the same result if the first input is of type `date`? So, now the second input is required only if the age provided in the first input is less than 18.

Comment: there is no need to use ids for form elements

Comment: why did you choose `multiple` in your select?

Comment: @MisterJojo because these days you can identify as both over and under 18. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the `required` attribute of the `parent_name` input every time the `over_18` selection changes.

Few notes:

- `type="parent_name"` is invalid, it should be `type="text"`.
- I think you've added `multiple` on `select` by mistake, it doesn't make any sense here.
- I've also made the initial option for `select` to be `Select Age` with `value=""`, so now you don't need `required` on `parent_name` in your HTML.

```js
const select = document.getElementById("over_18");
const parentInput = document.getElementById("parent_name");
const form = document.querySelector("form");

select.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  if (e.target.value === "No") {
    parentInput.required = false;
  } else {
    parentInput.required = true;
  }
});

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Submitted");
});
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="over_18">Over 18? </label>
    <select id="over_18" required>
      <option value="">Select Age</option>
      <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
      <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="parent_name">Parent Name</label>
    <input type="input" id="parent_name">
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Update based on OP's comment**:

If `age` is a `date` input:

- Calculate if the age is above 18 by comparing the year, month and date of the provided date with the current date.
- Then, toggle the `required` attribute accordingly.

```js
const ageInput = document.getElementById("age");
const parentInput = document.getElementById("parent_name");
const form = document.querySelector("form");

ageInput.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  const date = new Date(e.target.value),
    birthYear = date.getFullYear(),
    birthMonth = date.getMonth(),
    birthDate = date.getDate(),
    currYear = new Date().getFullYear(),
    currMonth = new Date().getMonth(),
    currDate = new Date().getDate(),
    years = currYear - birthYear,
    isAdult =
      years > 18 ||
      (years === 18 && currMonth > birthMonth) ||
      (years === 18 && currMonth === birthMonth && currDate >= birthDate);

  console.log("Is Adult?", isAdult);

  if (isAdult) {
    parentInput.required = false;
  } else {
    parentInput.required = true;
  }
});

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Submitted");
});
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="age">Age</label>
    <input type="date" id="age" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="parent_name">Parent Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="parent_name">
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: How can I go about doing this using a date field instead of a yes/no box and then automatically calculate if the entered date was more than 18 years ago, if it is more than 18 years ago from the current date then the parent_name field should not be required, else parent name field should be required.

Comment: @Bart I've updated my answer please check if it helps!

Comment: It is updating the required field, but now my submit button wont work

Comment: @Bart Sorry I didn't get that? The snippet in my answer isn't submitting?

Comment: Yes, when the age is more than 18 it is updating the required for parent_name correctly, However, the submit function won't work

Comment: It just says "Submitted"but yet its not submitting

Comment: @Bart Oh now I get you, the snippet in my answer has `e.preventDefault()` which prevents it from submitting, remove that line and it should submit. I've also removed the `name` attributes for brevity, so remember adding them back in your code.

Comment: Just spotted that there myself before you mentioned it, Removed it and it's working perfectly. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this :

```
  function updateRequirements() {
        var over_18 = document.getElementById('over_18').value;
        if (over_18 === 'No') {
            doccument.getElementById('parent_name').setAttribute('required', true);
        } else {
            doccument.getElementById('parent_name').removeAttribute('required');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks when I initially set up the form for parent_name should I set it to required? Or will the JS function override this and take care of handling the requirements?

Comment: @Bart It will change but depends on how you call function updateRequirements

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run your code but nothing happens because:
**1**.you need to add **onchange** attribute to your select tag or you can set this from javascript: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

```html
<select name="over_18" id="over_18" class="form-control" onchange="updateRequirements()" required multiple>
```

**2.** Instead of **doccument** use **documnet** and try something like this:

```js
    function updateRequirements() {
        var over_18 = document.getElementById('over_18').value;
        if (over_18 = 'No') {
            document.getElementById('parent_name').setAttribute('required', true);
        } else {
            document.getElementById('parent_name').setAttribute('required', false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add an `onchange` to your first input

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="over_18">Over 18? </label>
    <select name="over_18" id="over_18" class="form-control" required onchange="updateRequirements()">
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And then use your function

```
function updateRequirements() {
        var over_18 = document.getElementById('over_18').value;
        if (over_18 == 'No') {
            document.getElementById('parent_name').required = true;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('parent_name').removeAttribute("required");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).